# Get a first and last day of the month from month key

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a month key which look like this `"201208"`.

I am reading the data from SQL and returning as a `DataTable`.
Then I am looping through my `DataTable`.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
   Dim s As String = dr.Item(0)
Next
```

My `s` would be a string looking like this `"201208"`
How convert this string into `year, first day of the month and last day of the month`?
**Looking for a way to split the string into two seperate `dim`s.**

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: You are not new user. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to just parse the string as `Date`, then calculate the last day of the month.

Try the following:

```
Dim s = "201208"
Dim firstDay = Date.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMM", Nothing)
Dim lastDay = firstDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
Dim year = firstDay.Year
```

Comment: A few notes, `Date.ParseExact` doesn't compile, you need to use either `DateTime.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact`, I would recommend `DateTime.ParseExact`. Also there is no need to concatenate the "01" onto the string as .Net will create a DateTime object where the day property is "01" by default, this means that you can leave the "dd" part out of your format string

Comment: @JMK You're right about the `01` part being not needed. Fixed it. Thanks. But why should `Date.ParseExact` not compile? `Date` is just an alias for `DateTime`.

Comment: I am so sorry, Date.ParseExact does compile, but doesn't seem to show up in Intellisense! I'm used to C#, my bad!

Comment: @JMK Note that when using intellisense in VB.Net, there are two tabs in the dropdown list: `common` and `all`. I felt for that trap by myself multiple times :-)

Comment: You can switch your default tab by doing [ALT] + [.] to use the `All` tab and [ALT] + [,] to use the `common` tab. Make sure the intellisense "dropdown" is displayed for the default tab to change.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly I would use [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)  with format "ddMMyy" to parse the string into a DateTime.

Then I would use something like

```
Dim startDate As New DateTime(dbDate.Year, dbDate.Month, 1)
Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

to get the StartDate and EndDate

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Function FormatDate(ByVal dateKey As String) As String
    Dim x As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateKey, "yyyyMM", Nothing)
    FormatDate = String.Format("Year: {0}; First day of month: {1}; Last day of month: {2}", x.Year, x.AddDays(-x.Day).ToString("dddd"), x.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-x.Day).ToString("dddd"))
End Function
```

You can use this function as so:

```
Dim dateDetails As String = FormatDate("201208")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Split that string into a year and month (see [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx))
2. Use "1" as the first of the month -> that's your start date
3. Add one month, subtract one day -> that's your end date

Comment: How to split the string after 4th character for example?

Comment: @NewUser - year = s.Substring(1,4); month = s.Substring(4,2); then convert to integer.